# tvOS: customising UINavigationBar fonts

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, tvos, uiappearance

Ive been trying to customize the fonts used in a UINavigationBar in a tvOS app and I'm having problems with getting the font change to work. Here is my code:

```
CGFloat fontSize = ((UIFont *)self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes[NSFontAttributeName]).pointSize;
NSDictionary *appearance = @{
                             NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:fontSize * 2],
                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor]
                             };

// Navigation bar Title

// Using traits - works in iOS only
UITraitCollection *traits = [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithUserInterfaceIdiom:[[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]];
[[UINavigationBar appearanceForTraitCollection:traits] setTitleTextAttributes:appearance];

// Nav bar appearance - works in iOS only
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:appearance];

// Direct setting - works in iOS & tvOS
[self.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:appearance];

// Navigation bar Edit button

// Appearance - works in iOS only
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:appearance forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Direct - works in iOS only
[self.editButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:appearance forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

So far it appears that I can either directly set the font and colour of the title in iOS. But an only use direct setting in tvOS.

For my edit button, I simply cannot get anything to work in tvOS.

I was hoping to use the appearance proxies either directly or via traits.

***Anyone know why this is not working in tvOS?***

I can't seem to find much on the inter webs about customizing the appearance of tvOS apps.

P.S. I'm using XCode 7.3.1 and tvOS 9.2